# How do i query a Powershell for newly imaged PC's to then give me the names of all the people that last logged on

Tags: powershell, sccm

I would like to get a list of all the newly imaged laptops on the network and then get the name of all the people that had last logged on to them

```
$NewlyImaged =[DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-5)
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'WhenCreated -ge $NewlyImaged' -Properties 'WhenCreated' | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*LN-T*"} |Format-Table Name,WhenCreated,DistinguishedName,UserName -AutoSize -Wrap

ForEach-Object ($_.name) {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName}
```

```
Name            WhenCreated         DistinguishedName                                                             UserName
----            -----------         -----------------                                                             --------
LN-T48-PF11LRB0 31/07/2019 18:08:30 CN=LN-T48-PF11LRB0,OU=Laptops,OU=Win10,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com {}
```

I shouldnt be getting my own laptop's last login
UserName
COOLEY\khalifam

Comment: my understanding is that you should use DOUBLE quotes around the entire filter and SINGLE quotes around the variable. so replace >>> `-Filter 'WhenCreated -ge $NewlyImaged'` <<< with >>> `-Filter "WhenCreated -ge '$NewlyImaged'" <<< ///// the inner single quotes may not be needed since you are using a simple $Var, but it seems worth while to make a habit of it. [*grin*]

Comment: also, you never send ANYTHING to your `ForEach-Object` line.

Comment: also also, you use `Format-Table` and that should _almost NEVER_ be sent to anything other than the screen OR to a plain text file. so, even if you piped that line to your `ForEach-Object`, it would not work - the objects would be _formatting items_, not the objects you need.

Comment: So how would you re-structure the whole thing?

Comment: **_1st_** - run something like this >>> `Get-ADComputer -Filter "WhenCreated -ge '$NewlyImaged' -and Name -like '*LN-T*'" -Properties 'WhenCreated'` <<< and tweak it until you get the required items. **_2nd_** create a `ForEach-Object` that gathers the WMI info into a temp $Var. **_3rd_** still in the `F-O` block, use that new $Var and the object from the pipeline to build a `[PSCustomObject]` that has the desired properties. **_4th_** again, still in the `F-O` call, send that PSCO out to a collection. **_5th_* send that collection to a CSV file via `Export-CSV`.

Comment: Sorry but ill need a little more help doing that still a little new to this, what did you mean by - create a ForEach-Object that gathers the WMI info into a temp $Var. 3rd still in the F-O block, use that new $Var and the object from the pipeline to build a [PSCustomObject] that has the desired properties. 4th again, still in the F-O call, send that PSCO out to a collection. *_5th_ send that collection to a CSV file via Export-CSV

Comment: i do not have access to the AD stuff. so i am going from scripting logic. ///// **_1st_** have you been able to get the Get-ADComputer line to work with some variant of the filter i showed?